# When Kafka Topic partition reassignment, Flink job fails continuously

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

## env

- kafka 1.0.1
- flink 1.7.1

## trouble

I use topic with 200 partitions. and flink uses this topic. 
Recently, I do manual partition reassignment. 
When i reassigned partitions, Flink continuosly fails with this error.

**error1.**

```
[2021-07-28 18:21:15,926] WARN Attempting to send response via channel for which there is no open connection, connection id ..(kafka.network.Processor)
```

**error2.**

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for -126: 30042 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

**error3.**

```
java.lang.Exception: Error while triggering checkpoint 656 for Source: Custom Source -> Sink: ... (32/200)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task$1.run(Task.java:1174)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Could not perform checkpoint 656 for operator Source: Custom Source -> Sink: ... (32/200).
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.triggerCheckpoint(StreamTask.java:570)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.triggerCheckpoint(SourceStreamTask.java:116)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task$1.run(Task.java:1163)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Could not complete snapshot 656 for operator Source: Custom Source -> Sink: ... (32/200).
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.snapshotState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:422)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$CheckpointingOperation.checkpointStreamOperator(StreamTask.java:1113)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$CheckpointingOperation.executeCheckpointing(StreamTask.java:1055)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.checkpointState(StreamTask.java:729)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.performCheckpoint(StreamTask.java:641)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.triggerCheckpoint(StreamTask.java:564)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for ...-86: 30049 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

And When i restarted failed job, this error occurs continuously.

```
ClassLoader info: URL ClassLoader:
    file: '/blobStore-29c572a3-4ed4-48a6-b604-d93b7e4a9a10/job_8bd41a7e0690e75bd61d148d89dca963/blob_p-5c10d03a5cbb09c9a9459f1bc2a70804d0b08290-26b5562cbe83b0403b06717637e7ab47' (invalid JAR: /blobStore-29c572a3-4ed4-48a6-b604-d93b7e4a9a10/job_8bd41a7e0690e75bd61d148d89dca963/blob_p-5c10d03a5cbb09c9a9459f1bc2a70804d0b08290-26b5562cbe83b0403b06717637e7ab47 (Too many open files))
Class not resolvable through given classloader.
```

So I restarted all mesos and flink cluster with zookeeper clearance.
Is there any cause to look for?

Answer (score 1):

There were network issues with certain brokers in the cluster.
If a request for a specific partition is processed slowly due to a network issue, it is expected that the message will be displayed.

Subsequently, the job corresponding to the partition does not work properly, and it seems that the checkpoint issue of flink occurs.

This problem was solved by replacing the equipment of the broker.